# Is there a way to match routes in react-router-dom v6 based on whether the route exists in an object?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I recently migrated to `react-router-dom` v6, and there is one item I need to change which I am a bit confused with. Basically, I have routes at `/projects/:id` and I want to direct to `<Project />` if `id` exists in an object called `projects`, and to otherwise direct to `<NotFound />`.

I have this object:

```
    const projects = {
        sample: {
            // properties
        },
        sample2: {
            // properties
        },
        sample3: {
            // properties
        }
    }
```

But I am unsure how to check if the `id` in route matches any of the items in `projects` above, so I have the following, broken code:

```
    <Routes>
      <Route path="/" element={ <Home /> } />
      <Route path="/about" element={ <About /> } />
      <Route path="/projects/:id" element={ ({ match }) => (
        match ? <Project /> : <NotFound /> 
      )} />
      <Route path="*" element={ <NotFound /> } />
    </Routes>
```

Ideally, `/projects/sample2` should be a valid route, rendering `<Project />`, but `/projects/sample5` should not be a valid route, and therefore it should direct to `<NotFound />`.

I'm not sure what prop should be used and matched, and how to do it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `params.id in projects` in your `Route` or inside the `Project` component:

```
params.id in projects ? /* render project */ : <NotFound />
```

Comment: Where is the `params` object coming from? This logic makes sense, just not sure where it's coming from.

Comment: `const params = useParams();` https://reactrouter.com/en/main/hooks/use-params

Answer (score 1):

```
const isProject = !!Object.entries(projects).filter(sample=>sample[1].id ===id);

// provided that id is one of the keys in properties; 

element={isProject ? <Project /> : <NotFound /> }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try to changing in the following way:

```
<Routes>
  <Route path="/" element={ <Home /> } />
  <Route path="/about" element={ <About /> } />
  <Route path="/projects/:id" element={ <Project /> } />
  <Route path="/404" element={ <NotFound /> } />
  <Route path="*" element={<Navigate to="/404" replace />} />
</Routes>
```

In the `Project` component, you can use `useEffect` to redirect to `NotFound` page

```
const { id } = useParams();
const navigate = useNavigate();

...

useEffect(() => {
  if (/* ex: response.status == 404 || !id || ... */) {
    navigate("/notfound", { replace: true });
  }
}, [id, navigate]);
```